# Custom Page Template

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm attempting to add a custom page, that will not be associated with a particular type of piece or other set of data. It will be used to run actions for reporting and processing/showing data, so it needs to be fairly stand-alone. I want it to be a page type, so it will be handled in navigation the same way that any other page is. I mostly have it working, but am running into an issue - no matter how I set it up, when I try to navigate to an instance of the page that gets created, it always looks for the template in lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages instead of the module folder.

In this case, I'm currently calling the module test-item (will rename once I figure out what the issue is). So, I have a folder called lib/modules/test-item, with index.js and views/index.html. I also attempted to rename the template in the views folder to show.html and test-item.html just to be sure it wasn't a naming issue. Here's how the module is configured in index.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test-item',
    extend: 'apostrophe-custom-pages',
    construct: function(self, options) {
        //more logic stuff
    }
}
```

Also, if I add a field to the module, it does show up when I try to make a new page with the type test-item, so I know the module itself is being loaded.

In app.js, I have the module loaded with this:

```
'test-item': {},
```

The page type does not get added to the list of types in the new page dialog unless I add it to the apostrophe-pages module, so I added it like so:

```
types: [
    {
        name: 'test-item',
        label: 'Test Page'
    }
]
```

Do I need to do something different to get the module to load the template from lib/modules/test-item/views/index.html instead of throwing an error when it cannot find the template in lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages/test-item.html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apostrophe-custom-pages` templates still live in the project level `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/views/pages/MODULE-NAME.html`.

If you're trying to fully modularize a custom page as an npm module you can make an `improve` based module which can add a view to the `apostrophe-pages` module.

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify what you mean by an 'improve based module'? Is that supposed to be 'improved base module'? Wanted to make sure there wasn't a module somewhere called 'improve'.

Comment: No, not a module called improve. Instead of subclassing a module, you can target an existing module and give it extra functionality, templates, etc by improving it. Linked is a submodule of the `apostrophe-workflow` module that specifically targets schemas and adds additional front-end js, templates, and server code https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-workflow/tree/master/lib/modules/apostrophe-workflow-schemas